# Silex DoctrineORM: Custom Entity Repository

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex

I have an issue when trying to build a custom entity repository.

```
"PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Orm\EntityRepository' not found in /home/user/projects/app/src/Application/Database/EntityRepository/UserRepository.php on line 8
```

In the `CustomRepository.php` file I have done this:

```
<?php
    namespace Application\Database\EntityRepository;

    use Application\Bootstrap as Bootstrap;
    use Doctrine\Orm\EntityRepository;

    class UserRepository extends \Doctrine\Orm\EntityRepository
    {

        public function getPasswordByUsername($username)
        {
            $query = $app['orm.em']->createQuery('SELECT u.password FROM Application\Database\Entities\Users u WHERE (u.username = :username)');
            $query->setParameter('username', $username);

            return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
        }
    }
```

And then in my bootstrap file this method is loaded through a constructor in the bootstrap class.

```
use Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider as silexDocProv;
use Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider as silexSessProv;
use Dflydev\Silex\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider as docProv;

private function initDatabase()
{
    $this->app->register(new silexDocProvj(), array(
        'db.options' => array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'     => getenv('DBHOST'),
            'dbname'   => getenv('DBNAME'),
            'user'     => getenv('DBUSER'),
            'password' => getenv('DBPASS')
        )
    ));

    $this->app->register(new docProv(), array(
        'orm.em.options' => array(
            'mappings' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'yml',
                    'namespace' => 'Application\Database\Entities',
                    'path' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/Config/Mappings'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

And finally my mappings file has this:

```
Application\Database\Entities\Users:
    type: entity
    table: users
    repositoryClass: \Application\Database\EntityRepository\UserRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are case-sensitive.

Change

```
Doctrine\Orm\EntityRepository
```

to:

```
Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
```

Also there's no need for full namespace in

```
extends \Doctrine\Orm\EntityRepository
```

because you've imported the class by

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
```

so now you can just do:

```
extends EntityRepository
```